# Vagrant on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-b+

Is there a way to run Vagrant on a Raspberry Pi (B+)? I know that it would require a virtualization program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not really. It's theoretically possible to emulate `x86` code on an `ARM` machine using some form of virtualization, but the Raspberry Pi is not powerful enough to do it functionally.

Answer (score 2):

As Dan suggests Docker is a better option because there is far less strain on the host. Resin.io has done a lot more work since our initial experiments. It's now even easier than the `4 simple steps`. If you'd like to give it a try check out our [getting started guide](http://docs.resin.io/#/pages/installing/gettingStarted.md).

Disclaimer: I work for resin.io

Answer (score -3):

Use docker instead, it appears there are some pretty decent instructions for pi-users here:

https://resin.io/blog/docker-on-raspberry-pi-in-4-simple-steps/

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.